# Dns record pointing to a folder on a server

Tags: dns, subdomain

can't figure it out if it is possible to set up DNS record to a folder on a server. 
Say sub.example.com to point on 1.2.3.4/e2/

Is it possible somehow to point domains directly to folders on a server so I can have different domains hosted on one server within different folders?

Comment: Please post this question in ServerFault

[ServerFault FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq)
Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity


[StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible to host multiple domains on one server.  It is called [Virtual Hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting).

But you are confusing a few concepts.  DNS is for converting names to ip addresses.  The DNS system knows nothing about the folder structure.  That is the responsibility of the webserver.  You will configure Virtual Hosts on the web server.

The way this is normally done is to

1. Add host record (aka, A record) in DNS. For example, coolname.domain.com -> 12.34.56.78.
2. Configure webserver to read content for coolname.domain.com from folder of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

This is generally done with virtual hosting on your web server. DNS is not meant for that.

The closest you could do is use `TXT` records, but then no one other than you would be aware of that, so your clients wouldn't even know.

Comment: Thank you a lot, searched for it and already implemented. Although I feel i have to give tick to next replier since he has more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Apache webroot to the folder that you need. Apache can serve multiple sites with their own domains from a single server. Alternatively, for a temporary solution you can simple `cd` into the desired directory and run this python code:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```